# Не открывается phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, linux-mint, lamp

Использую Linux Mint 20.1.

Установил LAMP.

Работают ссылки

http://localhost/ -> показываются "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Pag"
http://localhost/info.php -> показывается вся информация начиная с заголовка PHP Version 7.4.3.

Установил phpMyAdmin командой

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Все установилось, но ссылка http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ выдает ошибку

> Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server.
> Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Что еще можно сделать? Установку производил по этой статье [How To Install LAMP Stack on Linux Mint 20](https://techviewleo.com/how-to-install-lamp-stack-on-linux-mint/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нету, она находится в etc.

Comment: Сделал так:  зашел как root, вырезал и перенес в папку www. Ввел в адресную строку localhost/phpmyadmin. Все равно не работает

Comment: Исправил выше))

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119450/discussion-between-denis-and-maximlensky).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выполнить по шагам

1. `sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Вставить в самый низ

2. `Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`

Что бы выйти из nano нажать `ctrl+x`

И перезагрузить apache