# Page not found при попытке доступа к Phpmyadmin | Apache

Tags: веб-программирование, apache, сервер, phpmyadmin

Устанавливал себе LAMP вот так:

```
sudo apt install lamp-server^
```

^ - это тоже часть команды. Все прекрасно установилось, php работает mysql тоже (пришлось правда создать нового пользователя в mysql для работы из php), apache тоже работает, ставил на ubuntu. И все прекрасно работает, но вот phpmyadmin - нет. При попытке написать localhost/phpmyadmin пишет 404 Not found... Попробовал удалить phpmyadmin и установить заново - не помогло.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, поспешил с вопросом. Оставлю здесь ответ, если кто-то наткнется на мой вопрос.

Решение в данной теме: [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1240943/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-phpmyadmin?rq=1)

По просьбе Spatz в комментариях прикреплю краткое решение проблемы:

Apache почему-то не добавляет конфигурацию phpmyadmin и это необходимо сделать вручную:

1. Открыть apache2.conf `sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
2. Подключить в конце файла файл конфигурации: `Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`

Comment: @Spatz обновил ответ